# What is devmode for snaps?

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

I have heard about the ability to use snaps in developer mode.

What is this mode and what can I use it for?

Answer (score 12):

Developer mode, or `devmode` in short, enables developers and users to install snaps without enforcing security policies, regardless of what is defined in the `snapcraft.yaml`. E.g.

```
sudo snap install notes --devmode
```

When installed this way, snaps behave in a similar way to traditional .deb packages in terms of accessing system resources. That is, snaps have access to the system without being restricted by app isolation and interfaces.

Developer mode is useful when:

- Testing a snap in the first stages of development to ensure it runs as expected
- Temporarily bypassing security enforcement if there is not yet an interface available that controls a particular system access required by the snap (for example for a snap that defines in it's `snapcraft.yaml` that it can only work in devmode, see below)

As a developer, you can also declare that the snap needs relaxed security requirements at the [snapcraft.yaml](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/snapcraft-syntax/) level by declaring `devmode` confinement instead of `strict`

```
confinement: devmode
```

You'll be then flagging users that this app specifically needs to be installed with `--devmode` to work. Not specifying the command line switch when installing will result in failure to install.

That is, users will have to specifically acknowledge that they will install your snap in developer mode.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning the new `confinement` property supported within the YAML (more info [here](https://github.com/ubuntu-core/snapcraft/blob/master/docs/snapcraft-syntax.md)).

Comment: Maybe also mention that apps with `confinement: devmode` can only be uploaded to the alpha/beta channels.

Comment: @dholbach thanks! Which channels are they exactly? I can see `beta`, but there doesn't seem to be an `alpha` channel in the [channels documentation page](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/guides/channels/) - other than a mention in the picture

Comment: David Callé tells me: «Alpha does not exist in the store (hence, it has been dropped from the channels doc that previously mentioned it), it's "edge" and "beta". The store UI also warns you during the upload step:  "If confinement is set to devmode, upload must target devel channels (beta, edge). Other channels will be excluded."»