# Ubuntu 20 - Chromium doesn't show anything in Recents

Tags: chromium, snap

I have a lot of files in `Recent`, and I can see them in apps like LibreWriter.

But when I want to upload a file somewhere form Chromium, I don't see those files in Recent.

This is really annoying because every time I want to open the file I just worked on (screenshot, document etc.) in Chrome, I need to navigate to its folder. After I upload a file, it appears in Chrome's `Recent`, but new recent files created in other apps, do not. This makes `Recent` useless in Chromium.

Is this because of the [short-sighted sandboxing due to snap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184357/why-cant-chromium-suddenly-access-any-partition-except-for-home)? How can I make Recent function normally?

Comment: There's `--devmode` which allows snaps to run without sandboxing, IIUC. So, `sudo snap remove package_name` followed by `sudo snap install package_name --devmode`. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/783945/what-is-devmode-for-snaps/.

Comment: The same hack of [creating a separate `.desktop` launched for Chromium snap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184357/why-cant-chromium-suddenly-access-any-partition-except-for-home/1251289#1251289), worked to let it properly access Recents.